# cakePHP form with YUI text editor, not working

Tags: forms, cakephp, yui-editor

I am trying to integrate yui editor in a cakephp form
the editor is attached to the textarea, I tried the `handleSubmit` option and it didn't work, so I went trying manual. so- I've attached a listener to the `onsubmit`, which is working.. or not.

Editor initialization ( a copy-paste from yui site, only element named changed):

```
(function() {
    //Setup some private variables
    var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom,
        Event = YAHOO.util.Event;  
        //The SimpleEditor config
        var myConfig = {
            height: '300px',
            width: '99%',
            focusAtStart: true
        };

    //Now let's load the SimpleEditor..
    var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor('ArticleContent', myConfig);
    myEditor.render();
})();
```

Initialization works fine (I assume) since the editor now holds the real content of that record field.

The `onsubmit` listener function:

```
function setTextArea()
{
alert('s');  
var dd = myEditor.saveHTML();  
alert('d');
return false;
}
```

The first alert is working, so the event is handled.
However, the second alert never happens. the form - somehow - is submitted before it.
and, the content is not saved.

further checks shows that ANY call to myEditor [even alert(myEditor)] is submitting the form...

anyone? help? i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to use tinyMCE....

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, but is any code in the 'saveHTML' function calling something that clashes with cakephp functions?

if this is the problem, you may be able to get around it by modifying the yui code function names (hacky i know, but unless there is some way to use a custom namespace for it i think you'd be stuck with it)

Comment: thanks, but i chose YUI cause i had the KISS idea in mind... so, no time.